# The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the object state manager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Im currently using Jtable to handle a list of eventtypes, but everytime I try to delete via the table I get the error "Value cannot be null. parameter name: entity".

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteEventType(EventType eventType)
    {
        using (var db = new ICTTBEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var newObj = db.EventTypes.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EventTypeID == eventType.EventTypeID);
                if (newObj != null)
                {
                    db.EventTypes.Remove(newObj);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
                }
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = "eventType is null" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
    }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You get eventType via another ICTTBEntities context, that's why it probably can't found it in your new context.

Try getting eventType from new context via Id.

Also, don't forget to Call SaveChanges on your context after removing the object.

Use

```
var newObj = db.EventTypes.Single( e => e.Id == eventType.Id);
db.EventTypes.Remove(newObj);
db.SaveChanges();
```